# Create time on a specific time zone irrespective of local timezone using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In my scenario, user enters the date and the timezone of that date.

The user may be in any timezone
Say, the given date is 2nd Feb 2015 06:00:00 for EST (GMT-0500).
The user is in IST (GMT+0530).

If i create a give,

```
var ScheduleOn = new Date('02/02/2015 06:00:00')
```

> ScheduleOn is **Mon Feb 02 2015 06:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)**

It is creating date in IST format.

I have tried specifying time zone also ( `var ScheduleOn = new Date('02/02/2015 06:00:00 UTC-0500')` ), it is not working.

I need time in the local time zone (IST) for the given time in the given timezone (EST).

What I need is  `ScheduleOn is Mon Feb 02 2015 16:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Comment: Something like this?

    var ScheduleOn = new Date('02/02/2015 06:00:00');
    var timeZoneDifference = -5;
    var ScheduleOnCorrected = new Date(ScheduleOn.getTime() + timeZoneDifference * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 60 min * 60 sec * 1000 milisec = 1 hour

Comment: Yes. But that timezone diff must be dynamic. I cant hardcode that

Comment: var x = new Date(); var timeZoneDifference = x.getTimezoneOffset()/-60; as in my earlier blog: http://webtrick101.blogspot.com/2013/08/my-javascript-function-to-show-utc-time.html